# hover effect for left menu not working

Tags: html, css, web, hover

I am trying to work on this really simple hover effect but I am not understanding where I am going wrong.The only thing I want to do is **change the color of the text to black on hover**. My code is as follows:
This is the css for a left menu

```
/* === Left Menu === */
.leftmenu{

width:200px;
text-align:center;  
}
.leftmenu ul
{
  list-style-type:none;

  width:200px;

  margin:0;
  padding:0;
 }
.leftmenu ul li
{
  width:200px;
  text-align:center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #005680;
}
.leftmenu ul li a
{
  display:block;
  text-decoration:none;
  background-color:#fff;
  color: #999;
  font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size:16px; 
  padding:8px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.leftmenu a:hover
{
  display:block;
  colour:#000;
  display:inline;   
}
```

This is the html code:

```
 <div class="leftmenu" align="center">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="ABOUTUS1.HTML">About Us</a></li>
     <li><a href="Nutrition.html">Nutrition Facts</a></li>
     <li><a href="Dist.html">Trade With Us</a></li>
     <li><a href="Contact.html">Get In Touch</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: you have a typo: colour:#000; 
                     ^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax Error : `colour:#000;` should be `color`, also you need to get rid of `display: inline;` property

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/HMj6C/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `display:inline` and color spelling is wrong

```
.leftmenu a:hover
{
  display:block;
  color:#000; 
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HMj6C/)**

Comment: colour isn't spelled wrong, but for css it is. Colour is how, we, the british spell it :)

Comment: That is how I use for color even out of css world

Comment: btw I knw that and I didnt start convers about the spellings. I use American English